# Primary key does not allow unique replace functionality

Tags: sqlite

```
CREATE TABLE resource_sync 
(
     _id INTEGER UNIQUE ON CONFLICT REPLACE PRIMARY KEY, 
     status_id INTEGER, 
     result_id INTEGER
);
```

In case two equal `_id` values get inserted, SQLite would throw an exception:

> [13:39:48] Error while executing SQL query on database 'test': UNIQUE
>   constraint failed: resource_sync._id

However, it allows for desired replaces in case primary key declaration is removed from table creation SQL.

Why is that?

Thanks.

Comment: This might be a stupid question, as I'm not familiar with the `ON CONFLICT` cause, but why are you adding a `UNIQUE` constraint to a primary key?

Comment: @KidCode, I want to replace existing values with new ones when the conflict is arisen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UNIQUE is ignored on primary keys.

The correct syntax, as shown in the [documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtable.html), is:

```
CREATE TABLE resource_sync
(
     _id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY ON CONFLICT REPLACE,
     status_id INTEGER,
     result_id INTEGER
);
```